# Move content if textarea is resized

Tags: html, css, resize, textarea

I have a textarea in a form and some content underneath the textarea. When I expand/resize the textarea the content underneath stays in place. How do I make the content underneath move along when the textarea is resized?

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="email.php">

<label for="company">
    <span>Company</span>
    <textarea spellcheck="false" type="text" name="company"></textarea>
    </label>
<input type="submit" value="send" class="send" />
    </form>
```

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gp8cLp2/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `position:absolute` to your textarea, that's why it doesn't push the content underneath.

If you can use a static or relative position on it, this will work.